# Converting List<String[]> for use in ng-repeat

Tags: c#, arrays, list

So Im a bit stuck on where to go with this. Im handling the upload of csv data.

If the data has 10 columns I am to filter out any columns which are not previous defined in the database. So far so good....

I end up with `List<String[]>` which looks something like this, where each array is a column of data.

```
["key", "11111", "222222", "33333", "44444", "55555", "66666", "777777"]

["Group", "9852", "9852", "9852", "9852", "9852", "9852", "9852", "9852", "9852", "9852"]

["Types"Group", "Group", "Group", "Group", "Group", "Group", "Group", "Group", "Group"]

["Price", "0.625711406", "5.631402651", "3.441412731", "4.692835542", "6.014119336", "16.64599505"]
```

How do I convert a `List<String[]>` so the first entry of every array would be a whole record as below, without knowing the number of columns

```
[{"11111", "9852", "Group", "0.625711406"},
{"222222", "9852", "Group", "0.62571140"}] etc
```

I would be grateful for any ideas

Comment: If you're going to down vote please be constructive and say why

Comment: Not a down-voter, but I think it is related to your question being too broad. StackOverlow requires more focused questions. E.g. you tried to create an Web.API action, coded some HTML and AngularJS controller and you have a specific error.

Comment: Thanks Alexei I have made the answer more specific

Answer (score 0):

This question is too broad, but I will provide a few tips to get you started. Take a look upon [this article](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/cd7c2e/show-data-in-grid-format-using-angularjs-and-web-api/):

1. Define the table in HTML. The `ng-repeat` can be used for `tr`s:
2. Write the code to perform the data fetch from the server (Web.API or similar)

   ```
   $http({  
           url: "endpoint",  
           dataType: 'json',  
           method: 'GET',  
           data: '',  
           headers: {  
               "Content-Type": "application/json"  
           }  
       }).success(function (response) {  
           debugger;  
           $scope.entityList = response;  
       })  
          .error(function (error) {  
              // error handling here
          });
   ```
3. Write the API code (basically a controller action that should handle call from AngularJS).

**NOTE:** code provided in the article is just to get you started and you should refactor you application to have a clear separation between controller action code and data fetch code (thin controller).

Comment: I obviously have not been clear enough. I am organising this data on the server as the response to a HTTP call. I thought the fact it was a List<String[]> would of shown it was a server side language. I will make this clearer